# costum layout list view app crash

Tags: android, view, android-activity

i want to change the text color on a listview and i found out that i should be done using and costumlayout in xml. but when i tried it it made my app crash.

this is my activity :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/table_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.wowquiz.Scoreboard"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/abc_action_bar_title_text_size"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_title_text_size"
    android:background="@drawable/vraagbackground"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/highscore"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="244dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewScores"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/abc_action_bar_title_text_size"
        android:background="@drawable/vraagbackground"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white" >

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/abc_action_bar_title_text_size"
    android:background="@drawable/restartbutton"
    android:onClick="Back" />
```

and this is my .java

```
    public void readScore() { 
    final List<String> scores = db.getScoreNames();
    db.getMin();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.Costumlayout, android.R.id.text1, scores);
    final ListView listViewScores = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewScores);
    listViewScores.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and this is my costumlayout.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
     />
```

i only want the color to be white in order to make it more readable.

thanks in advance

Comment: did you take a look at the logcat output?

Answer (score 0):

the `android:id` you have supplied for your layout is incorrect.

when you create your `ArrayAdapter` here:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.Costumlayout, android.R.id.text1, scores);
```

you are telling the adapter to look for a `TextView` with the ID **`android.R.id.text1`**

however, in your XML layout, you have given the `TextView` the ID **`R.id.listTextView`** which won't match.

If you change your XML to the following, it should work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
 />
```